# Climb up/along/across-which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct/perfect and why(on the basis of difficulty level)?
"He climbed up/along/across a ledge."
"They climbed up/along/across a slope "
 we know "across"refers to the movement from one end to another,but is this movement horizontal or vertical or slope type?
And is there any other difference between up,along and across except the fact they refer to a specific type of movement?

Comment: What are you envisioning when you write it?  You pick the word that will convey that vision.

Comment: @HotLicks I just wanted to know if these three sentences are correct or not...but actually I did envision that this situations will be difficult...

Comment: This question Is broad enough to be climbed simultaneously _along_ and _across_. A ledge deserves a distinct kind of climbing than the kind used _on_ a slope.

Comment: One can even [climb **down** the slope](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22climb%20down%20the%20slope%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 3):

A ledge is horizontal, so it's possible to climb up *to* it, but not *up* it. *Along* is from one end to the other, *across* is from one side to the other (the back to the front or vice versa).

*Up a slope* is from bottom to top, *along* or *across a slope* would describe a roughly horizontal movement on a sloping surface.

Comment: Are across/along applicable in case of ledge?

Comment: I disagree that you can't "climb up a ledge". That would mean you start below the ledge, and pull yourself up on top of it. The phrase seems pretty commonly used, particularly when describing the move in many video games where your character climbs on top of a torso-height wall. They're climbing up a ledge.

Comment: Certainly you can move along a ledge. Since ledges are usually narrow, _across_ is less likely.

Comment: Can't *across* also refer to a left-to-right (or vice versa) movement? It doesn't have to be between front and back.

Comment: @nnnnnn I suppose it could, although _along_ seems more natural to me.

Comment: @NuclearWang yeah...that sounds correct too